# Winforms: Backgroundworker on abort method?

Tags: winforms

Is there an event for onAbort for the backgroundworker control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. When you call `CancelAsync` on the `BackgroundWorker` you need to handle the cancellation yourself. This then gets passed through to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, however you can tell that it was cancelled through `e.Cancelled`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no specific event for "Cancel event".

You really should look at the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx